# Cannot invoke "String.split(String)"

Tags: java, archivo

Buenas me esta dando un problema con el split ya que me dice que no se puede invocar porque la cadena es nula. Sin embargo el metodo split lo tengo dentro de un bucle while en el que solo se entra si la cadena es distinto de null.
Este metodo lo estoy usando para leer un archivo donde se encunetran nombre " " contraseña. No se porque sucede esto si alguien me pudiera ayudar. Gracias
Aqui dejo el codigo:

```
  public static boolean comprobarUsuario(String nombre){
    boolean existe = false;
    //Linea que se lee del archivo
    String linea;
    //Arreglo que contiene el nombre y la contraseña
    String[] nombreArchivo;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("credenciales.cre"));
        linea = br.readLine();
        while(linea != null && !existe){
            //Guardamos solo el nombre que es lo que nos interesa
            nombreArchivo = linea.split(" ");
            //Lo comparamos con el nombre que ingreso el usuario por teclado
            if(nombreArchivo[0].equals(nombre)){
                existe = true;
            }
            linea = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return existe;
}
```

Comment: Hola fantasticmaceta, como bien señalas, es imposible que entres al while con un valor "null" en ***linea***, osea que no es aquí donde está el problema, deberías verificar donde tienes otro *split* y si está recibiendo una cadena nula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error *"Cannot invoke "String.split(String)*" se produce cuando intentas llamar al método `split()` en una cadena que es nula. Es posible que el problema se esté produciendo en la primera iteración del bucle while, donde la variable línea todavía no ha sido inicializada.

Para evitar este error, puedes agregar una comprobación adicional antes de llamar al método `split()`, para asegurarte de que la cadena no es nula. Por ejemplo:

```
while (linea != null && !existe) {
    if (!linea.trim().isEmpty()) { // Verifica que la línea no esté vacía
        nombreArchivo = linea.split(" ");
        if (nombreArchivo[0].equals(nombre)) {
            existe = true;
        }
    }
    linea = br.readLine();
}
```

En este caso, la función `trim(`) elimina los espacios en blanco al principio y al final de la línea, y luego se verifica si la línea no está vacía antes de llamar al método `split()`. De esta manera, se evita llamar al método `split()` en una cadena nula o vacía, lo que debería solucionar el error que estás experimentando.

Comment: Me ha servido de mucha ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error completo debe ser:

> NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.split(String)" because
> "string" is null

Me parece que en este caso puede existir la posibilidad de que el valor de linea dentro del while tenga valor null:

```
  ...
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("credenciales.cre"));
        linea = br.readLine();
        while(linea != null && !existe){
            //Guardamos solo el nombre que es lo que nos interesa
            nombreArchivo = linea.split(" ");
  ...
```

cambia la validación de esta forma para asegurar el valor de linea no sea null:

```
  ...
        //linea = br.readLine();
        //while(linea != null && !existe){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("credenciales.cre"));
        while((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //Guardamos solo el nombre que es lo que nos interesa
            nombreArchivo = linea.split(" ");
  ...
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda